# How to retrieve the ICCID from the Enfora GSM0308-11

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem

I am working with the Enfora GSM0308-11 and need to retrieve the ICCID from the SIM. Getting the IMSI and IMEI appears easy enough, but I seem to be stuck with regard the ICCID, which I need in order to determine which APN to use.

Anyone have any ideas? I've been reading PDFs and googling, but I'm either being blind or the means to get it is simply eluding me.

EDIT:

I should add, I have tried all of the following to no avail. They all return an "ERROR" response from the modem.

```
RadioComm( "AT+CRSM\n\r" );
RadioComm( "AT+CSIM\n\r" );
RadioComm( "AT^ICCID\n\r" );
RadioComm( "AT+ICCID\n\r" );
RadioComm( "AT+CCID\n\r" );
RadioComm( "AT+CICCID\n\r" );
RadioComm( "AT$ICCID\n\r" );
```

This also produces an ERROR response...

```
RadioComm( "AT+CLAC\n\r" );
```

The AT+CIMI command, however, does return me the IMSI as I would expect.

Comment: Notice that [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) requires AT command lines to be terminated with `\r` only. You should not use `\n\r`.

Comment: I know I'm *really* late responding to this. For whatever reason, I never got notice that there were comments or responses to this question. That said, thank you for the heads up on this and I've made that change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AT$ICCID? Should do the trick I think. You were close :)

UPDATE #1:

Ok, on further looking around it seems this modem doesn't even have anything implemented to get the ICCID. Based upon http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/876256.pdf which is in theory the AT Command Set  reference for the device.

UPDATE #2:

Based on the suggested answer from hlovdal here is the command you could use:

```
AT+CRSM=176,12258,0,0,10
```

Tried this just now on a Sierra Wireless modem with success! <176> is the command type which is READ_BINARY, <12258> is the file location of the ICCID on the SIM card and the rest is parameters and response code I think.

You will get a response back something like:

+CRSM: 144,0,"2143658709"

The "2143658709" is in binary coded decimal format with switched digits. So in this example it would turn out to be "1234567890".

Learning some new cool stuff here :)

Comment: Interesting modem you have there. Plenty of gsm non standard commands built in! Tip from me is when you can't find stuff for a particular model then look for manufacturers AT command set documentation.

Comment: The AT$ICCID command doesn't work for it, either. You have to be careful that you're looking at the correct doc... the GMS0308-11 and the GSM3G to not share a common command set (unfortunately). Unless I'm being blind, I don't see any command in the GMS0308-11 for ICCID (admitting that I'm new enough to all of this that if they are using a term other than ICCID or SIM ID for the value, I might not be recognizing it for what it is)

Comment: All other manufacturers use ICCID or CCID. This modem is an oem modem right? Sometimes manufacturers are not so forthcoming with online documentation.

Comment: That is correct. ~le sigh~ I'm going to have to do some deep digging, I guess, and see if I can come up with it. And, to be honest, I don't see a way in their command set to fetch the phone number off the SIM either.

Comment: Fetching the phone number is a hit and miss thing. Usually you can't get it but sometimes you have luck. Don't rely on CNUM to save the day ;)

Comment: Might be worth reaching out to someone at www.novatelwireless.com. As far as I can see they bought enfora

Comment: ~le sigh~ I never got a notification that you had edited this and totally missed the update. That said, you hit the nail on the head. Thank you! Given that you beat user4758657 by about a year on the answer, I've given you the check, though I wish I could give it to both since it was his answer that flagged me this thread had a solution in it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to read ICCID from an SIM EF using `AT+CRSM`, searching for `ICCID "AT+CRSM"` in search engines seems to give some results indicating that is possible.

This command is one of the more non-intuitive and typically poorly documented AT command. To use it you have to invest effort in understanding the "file system" and addressing of files on the SIM. It is several years since I was involved in using this command so I cannot give a more detailed answer now.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the answer in the right direction. Sorry I didn't see it before now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using AT$ICCID?

```
at$iccid?
$ICCID: 89014103243534707921
OK
```

The CRSM command above also works, but you get the digits nibble swapped:

```
AT+CRSM=176,12258,0,0,10
+CRSM: 144,0,98101430425343079712
OK
```

Depending on the carrier, the MSISDN can be read with:

```
at+cnum
+CNUM: ,"18885551212",129
OK
```

But not all carriers store the MSISDN in the SIM.

Comment: I wish I could give two people the check on this, but aldridmc's answer beat you by almost a year even though it was your answer that brought me back to the thread. I do *truly* appreciate your input. Thank you.